# xubuntu 22.04 boot order change

Tags: grub2, boot-order

I need to change the boot order. I'd like it to go to usb, then cd, and finally my ssd.

Computer is an old HP Pavilion - sucks.

Comment: Boot order is determined by *firmware* settings (ie. uEFI or BIOS settings) on your hardware, and not the OS. This is a Ubuntu Q&A site, where you're asking a hardware/firmware question which is determined by your Pavilion box & firwmare you're using on it (ie. possibly what updates you've applied from HP)

Comment: Everything is locked. Only thing that is selected is OS boot manager, cannot select usb, or cd. The os boot manager is Grub2. Assumed something changed in 22.04 and was hoping to avoid HP.

Comment: If your laptop is uefi you might be able to change boot order via `efibootmgr` but be careful as you can brick your laptop if you make a mistake (or the bios has a bug, first check online to see what are others' experience with your model and efibootmgr)

Comment: Thanks, this hp is such a pain, but I like the 17 inch monitor